# Config File for Semantic Logging Application Block using in-process

Tags: c#, config

I am using Semantic Logging Application Block (SLAB) for in-process logging in C# language.
My requirement states that i should be able to change the EventLevel of the listener without having to re-compile the Code:-

Eg:-

```
var listener1 = new ObservableEventListener();
listener1.EnableEvents(RepositoryLog.Log, EventLevel.Verbose);
listener1.LogToConsole();
```

After having searched the internet i only found that you need a config file to do that. But since it is an in-process logging, SLAB does not provide any in-built Config File.
So i want a way through which i can achieve the requirement, either by creating a Config file or else by any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explicitly stated that with in-process SLAB, all configuration is performed in code, while when using the SLAB out-of-process, all configuration is performed in an xml config file.
So, what you need is not supported out of the box and you can only do it by writing all the plumbing yourself, an example of which I am yet to encounter. It is obvious that SLAB is primarily meant to be used out-of-process so it can use Event Tracing for Windows infrastructure (which it won't do if you use it in-process). However, the last docs I encountered state that the out-of-process SLAB is not yet considered production-ready... quite strange from Microsoft.